# Unregister Receiver is it necessary?

Tags: android, receiver

I have an alarm manager whose receiver I had registered in my code. The whole point of having an alarm manager in case of `Timer` is that it should run in background when in Pause state. Now, do I unregister it in `onPause()` or in `OnDestroy()` and will it still run in background and wake up and the receiver would receive it?

**EDIT:**

```
   @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyClass.class);
    i.putExtra("fromReciever", true);
    startActivity(i);

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you register it in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Example:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.android.MyReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.example.android.USER_ACTION" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This will keep your receiver registered as long as the application is installed on your device. All you have to do is implement it:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
      Toast.makeText(context, "Intent Detected.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
```

And you are set.

Additionally, you can check out [this tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_broadcast_receivers.htm) for more information.

**Added**

If you want to resume your `Activity` you can add this code in your `Receiver` `onReceive` method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("fromOnReceive", true);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

Then, in your `Activity onCreate` method, you check if it was called from your `Receiver`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if(getIntent().hasExtras()){
        boolean fromReceiver = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("fromOnReceive");
        if(fromReceiver)
            //Do work 
    }
}
```

Comment: But then on waking up I want it to do something over there in that Activity which is running a number of things. Basically its running my state machine.

Comment: You can easily start that activity with a start intent. I'll update my answer and add the code needed for that. @JourneyWithAndroid

Comment: Yes, sorry, that's my fault. You have to call `startActivity()` in your `broadcastReceiver onReceive` method like so: `context.startActivity(intent);` see my updated answer. @JourneyWithAndroid

Comment: @JourneyWithAndroid You can choose what you'd like, I've only provided an example.